# How to bind VSFTPD to a specific domain name on a shared hosting?

Tags: 16.04, server, ftp, vsftpd

Good day. I have a Ubuntu 16.04 VPS, on which I configured a shared hosting with two virtual hosts on the same IP (eg. domain1.com and domain2.com). I want to run the FTP server, and I want only domain1.com allowed, but not domain2.com. I was adviced to use VSFTPD to do that, but I couldn't find any howto. Please help. And sorry for bad English :)

Comment: If you uses `iptables` simply add this `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -m string --string "Host: domain2.com" --algo bm -j DROP`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All needed `iptables` commands

clear existing chains

```
sudo iptables --flush
sudo iptables --delete-chain
```

allow loopback

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
```

allow all ICMP

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p icmp --icmp-type any -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
```

allow established connections

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
```

allow public services
but deny ftp for domain `domain2.com

FTP

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 21 -m string --string "Host: domain2.com" --algo bm -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 21 -j ACCEPT
```

HTTP

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

HTTPS

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
```

SSH

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
```

allow forward

```
sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

deny all accept above rules

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -j DROP
```

default policies

```
sudo iptables -P INPUT DROP
sudo iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
```

save

```
sudo service iptables save
```

Comment: The answer suits my needs for now, thanks you. In future I plan to switch to proftpd with its virtual hosts.

Comment: `vsftpd` or `proftpd` uses `ftp` protocol and if you user default `active` setup port is the same `21`. This `iptables` setup will work. :)